# sql server table with required field in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I have a requirement with a table having two columns sourceTable and SourceColumn. I need to check all the field inside sourceColumn in table SourceTable and if value found return true else false.

Example:

| ReqId | SourceColumn | SourceTable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HomePhone | Phone |
| 2 | OfficePhone | Phone |
| 3 | State | Address |
| 4 | HomeAddress | Address |

So there are Phone and address table also. I need to check Homephone and OfficePhone column in Phone table and HomeAddress and State in address table for an employee if all 4 field are not null or blank return true else false. I tried using while loop with dynamic sql and it does not work. saying command executed successfully. although it has select statement.
Appriciate.

Comment: You can easily get the details of what columns a table has using the `sys` objects (the object with the columns is helpfully (and unsurprisingly) called `sys.columns`).

Comment: Side note, good spelling in your objects is important. You have one column called `SorceTable` and the other is called `SourceColumn`; the spelling of `Source` is inconsistent (and presumably incorrect in the former).

Comment: This question is kind of all over the place. What would really help here is providing the table definition in a format that makes sense (create table would be ideal) and then an explanation of what you want as output.

Comment: Please show what code you have currently